# can Android Adobe Air download and run SWF files with code?

Tags: android, adobe, air

Can Android Adobe Air download SWF files with code?
In my flash Web application I can download code for some sub game and run it dynamically.
Now I need to write application for Android with Adobe AIR and leave the same functionality as in Web version, so can I download swf file from internet and then start it via Adobe AIR??
Thanx!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is possible to download and run SWF files, but with some restriction:
http://help.adobe.com/en_US/air/security/WS485a42d56cd196415cc29732124ef23decb-7ffa.html
We have no access to file system.
There can be two solutions:
http://blogs.adobe.com/emalasky/2008/04/remote_plugins.html
1) Use Sandbox Brigde API (to communicate between separate sandboxes)
2) Sign modules and import it directly to application sandbox

Additional resource:
http://www.hufkens.net/2008/09/loading-remote-swf-files-in-air/